# Drop-down menu display problems

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu

I am working on a project and I am assigned to show a drop-down menu for the [website](http://srikaliastrologer.com/sri/index.html) , I mean Drop down menu but I dont know what am I doing wrong here. Can anyone help me out ?

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6qqi3.png)

Comment: Can you show us your code so far ? Avoid directly linking to the problematic website and report your code here. See [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is with overflow hidden for this div "**.content, .container**. "

removing this will show the full dropdown but make sure this won't make any other issues for your website.

Comment: yes i remove the overflow hidden Then  the drop down is working in desktop view.  but  not working  in mobile view  can any one help  me out?